# Mma lags when scrolling down in laptop

Tags: front-end, version-10

I have installed Mma 10.0 in my thinkpad T480s and when scrolling (even without having loaded anything in the Mma kernel), it lags.
Is there a way to avoid it/fix it?

Comment: You need to be more specific: can you give your `$Version` output please? Operating system version? RAM size and CPU speed and core count?

Comment: `$Version="10.0 for Linux x86 (64-bit) (June 29, 2014)"`, OS Debian, RAM size 7GB, CPU, core count 8, CPU speed CPU MHz: 754.101 MHz

Comment: I'd update. 10.0 is very old at this point, and admittedly one of the less stable releases.